# Homology of a solid torus with a circle removed

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I have this homework problem:

Consider the space $X$ obtained by removing a circle like the one in the picture from a solid torus. Let $T$ the exterior torus and $f:T\rightarrow X$ the canonical inclusion. Let $[c]$ a generator of $H_{2}^{sing}(T).$ Is it true that $f_{*}([c])$ generate $H_{2}^{sing}(X)$?[image]

My conjecture is that the answer to the question is yes and, in order to prove that, I tried to prove that $H_{2}(T,X)=H_{3}(T,X)=0$ and thus $f_{*}$ is an isomorphism. To prove that I tried to use the sequence associated to the triple $(T,X,T_{S})$ where $T_S$ is the solid torus but I think I do not understand the morphisms involved in the last sequence. Can you give me some help to understand that morphisms or, maybe, give me some hint or suggestion to a better approach to the problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you only remove the circle (which produces a space with two components) or the complete disk bounded by the circle?

Comment: Moreover, I ams sure you do not consider the solid torus, but the torus as a $2$-surface.

Comment: Just removing de circle (S^1). The circle is in the interior of the solid torus and does not intersect the boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

> Try using Mayer-Vietoris for the decomposition $S^1\times D^2=X\cup N(S^1)$, where $S^1\times D^2$ is the original solid torus from the picture and $N(S^1)$ is a tubular nbhd of your circle inside the solid torus, hence again it is homeomorphic to $S^1\times D^2$. (What is the intersection of $X$  and $N(S^1)$?)

<strike>Btw, $T$ should not be taken as the one you described in this post, i.e. it is not the boundary of an original solid torus.</strike>

Edit:
As you mention in the comments the generator can be taken as the image under the map $i:V\rightarrow X$. On the other hand, note that $i(V)-T$ is a boundary of $X$, hence it is a homological boundary, so $i(V)$ and $T$ are homologically equivalent.

Comment: Ok. The intersection $X\cap N$ is $S^{1}\times(D^2\setminus\{p\}$ which is homotopic to a torus $V=S^1\times S^1.$ With this it follows by Mayer-Vietoris that $H_{2}(V)$ is isomorphic to $H_{2}(X)$ being $i_{*}$ an isomorphism (where $i:V\rightarrow X$ is the canonical inclusion). Now, can I relate this to the question about $T$? (the exterior torus).   Anyway, thank you very much, I liked very much your answer.

Comment: @Nsn998 I edited my answer. Your question in the original post seems to have a positive answer as I was not quite realizing at the beginning :)